# How can I programmatically copy drivers in C#?

Tags: c#, driver

I'm looking to build an application to backup and probably restore drivers.

Can anyone enlighten me as to how I might approach this?

It seems ( from my perspective at the moment... ) that all I really need to know is where in the {registry?} I might find a listing of hardware and associated driver files? At that point, it seems that all I'd need to do is copy the files and retain some database of their association.

I suppose the question is effectively - 'Am I right in my assumption that I'll find such a listing in the registry?' and 'Where might I find it?'

Although I suppose some searching would suffice, I'd like to verify my theory before I go digging around.

Comment: Downvote, close vote, and no comment why? Thanks much.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but the question may be interpreted by some as a bit broad and/or not specific enough.

Comment: Fair. I just edited it to ask my actual question(s) more specifically at the end. Thanks.

Comment: I'm quite aware of those classes - how are they pertinent? I understand that those are the classes I'll likely use to actually copy the files - but finding them is my curiosity.

Comment: You can get all the files in a local File System and all attached drives using them.  You can get file system changes with the watcher.  Then I would advise implementing everything within a windows service so it runs all the time.

Comment: DriveRs, not drives. I think is the disconnect here...

Comment: What is the real problem you are trying to solve? Most drivers have custom housekeeping that the installers want to do when installing/uninstalling, like (un)registering with Windows. This may take the form of writing to the registry but also notification to the kernel that a driver has become (un)available.

Comment: I'm trying to build an application that I can run on any given computer that will backup all of its drivers to X location for later restoration. If this means observing said housekeeping, that's fine - and thank you for bringing it up - but that's all I'm trying to achieve. A driver backup, whatever that entails. I'm curious what all it may entail ( as you've expanded on ), and perhaps some approaches to gathering information around such nuances so as to process them properly.

Comment: Yep you're right I read drives.  My bad :)

Comment: Lol no sweat - thanks for the attempt. Doesn't seem to be a popular question for reasons I can't explain, so you're my best friend right this second.

Comment: It sounds like this information might be available in the registry. Have you tried actually searching the registry? I think it's a fair enough question, but it shows little research since you should be able to tell fairly easily if the registry is the right place to look.

Comment: If you're trying to back things up while the OS is running, many of the driver files may not even be readable.  You'll get sharing violations galore.  Using a pre-boot or another OS to do it?

Comment: Jan - while that is a brilliant approach, I've not the foggiest place where in the registry to start, or what to search for. While I suppose I could find that information somewhere on the internet, I also have curiosities around what other nuances I might encounter. Clay - thank you for the truly valid point. At the moment I'm intending to run this in a windows environment, but now that you mention it I might consider a linux boot and a C/++ build, however, utilizing the registry in this case would be much more difficult and I may have to compromise one way or the other for time's sake.

Comment: [DriverBackup! on SourceForge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/drvback/) might give you some insight - or eliminate the need for your to write any code at all.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks Sam.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can find the driver services in the registry: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services`

If you want to know where the binary file is located, you can look at the `ImagePath` and it will tell you where the file is located.

For example, the DiskClass driver will be located at `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\disk`, and the `ImagePath` will tell you that the binary file is at `System32\drivers\disk.sys`

Hope this helps.

Comment: VERY much. THANK you.